# What is Best Practice in BigQuery configration management?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know BigQuery's configration management Best Practice.

I want RollBack My Bigquery Project if missing...

cloud deploy manager?  API?

help me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on writing a good question. It's hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: sorry.  my english was broken..

I wanna BigQuery project configration managemant 

for example,  Backup configration definisions as file (datasets, ddls, views,,,,, All project resorces but exclude records) 

or  manage revisions of bigquery configration (like git, maquree, svn)

"Cloud deployment manager" can use this Use case?

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/

what is general approach?

please help me..

Comment: Sometimes people will create a separate 'dev' instance of their datasets, tables, views, etc. and only modify their 'prod' entities by copying from 'dev'. I don't think you can use the Cloud Deployment Manager with BigQuery.